# Android navigation button up on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I developed an application that contains a homescreen with an article list.
If you click on it, you access the detail in another screen.

I implemented the ActionBarSherlock, so I used the "up" button pattern for this activity.

Then I added a widget to this application. When you click on the widget, you access directly the detail activity.

The "up" button has been implemented following the Google recommandations (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html).

My problem is that on API Level 15 and below, it works perfectly. It calls the following code :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(Activity activity, Intent targetIntent) {
    String action = activity.getIntent().getAction();
    return action != null && !action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
}
```

But on JellyBean, the code used is :

```
public boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(Intent targetIntent) {
    try {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName cn = targetIntent.getComponent();
        if (cn == null) {
            cn = targetIntent.resolveActivity(pm);
        }
        ActivityInfo info = pm.getActivityInfo(cn, 0);
        if (info.taskAffinity == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return !ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().targetTaskAffinityMatchesActivity(mToken, info.taskAffinity);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The first part of the method retrieves information on the activity that should be loaded if stack must be recreated.

But I still don't understand what does the line :

```
!ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().targetTaskAffinityMatchesActivity(mToken, info.taskAffinity);
```

Can anyone help me on this line, I really need to find out how to obtain true by initializing everything well ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a boolean method it has to return something. If it needs to return a true boolean variable for it work, you have to do so!

From the official Documentation:

```
Returns true if the app should recreate the task when navigating 'up' 
from this activity by using targetIntent.

If this method returns false the app can trivially call navigateUpTo(Intent)
using the same parameters to correctly perform up navigation. 
If this method returns false, the app should synthesize a new task stack by using 
TaskStackBuilder or another similar mechanism to perform up navigation.
```

> The affinity indicates which task an activity prefers to belong to. By default, all the activities from the same application have an affinity for each other. So, by default, all activities in the same application prefer to be in the same task. However, you can modify the default affinity for an activity. Activities defined in different applications can share an affinity, or activities defined in the same application can be assigned different task affinities.

Comment: I need infomation on the specific code that returns true or false, to be able to create the right intent for the right case. For me, your answer is empty, of course if a method needs to return a boolean, you have to return a boolean...

Comment: Check my answer again. I added stuff from Official Doc!

Comment: I also edited my question. I know what is the aim of the method, I explained that I use it for the up navigation pattern. My only problem is how to well initialize my intent or manifest or any other file to obtain the "true" value.

Comment: Added more stuff! Maybe it helps more. I guess it searches for the default Affinity of your current Activity and returns a boolean based on the fact that it matches the appropriate affinity or it doesnt match it. Couldn't find more for it!